How database operations In Spring changes Java objects?
When I delete a category by using the deleteCategory method it's deleted from the category table, as it should be. And if I do something like:  categoryRepository.findByRestaurant_id(id);
it will give me the correct response with the current categories. But with those I never changed the restaurants.getCategories() object, yet it still changed. My question is, how is this working internally? Are these operations happening at the Database level but also at the Object level?
    @Override
    public CategoryDto createCategory(CategoryDto categoryDto,long userId) {

        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantRepository.findByUser_id(userId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new RuntimeException("Resource not found"));

        Category category = mapToEntity(categoryDto);
        category.setRestaurant(restaurant);
        restaurant.addCategory(category);
        Category savedCategory = categoryRepository.save(category);

        return mapToDto(savedCategory);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCategory(long categoryId) {

        Category category = categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("category", "id", categoryId)
        );
        categoryRepository.delete(category);
    }

package com.coskun.jwttoken.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Product> products;


}


package com.coskun.jwttoken.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Restaurant {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "restaurant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        this.categories.add(category);
    }

}


I tried to debug to see what was going on but couldn't find any solution.

Changes are made internally. What a solution do you find?
